# Can't generate Birt Report, Report engine fails to initialize null emitter

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

I'm using BIRT Runtime Release Build: 4.4.1
I'm facing EngineException when I try to generate a Birt report.
Here is the code:

```
        try {
        final EngineConfig config = new EngineConfig();
        // delete the following line if using BIRT 3.7 (or later) POJO
        // runtime
        // As of 3.7.2, BIRT now provides an OSGi and a POJO Runtime.

        config.setEngineHome("C:/Mine/ReportEngine/lib");
        // config.setLogConfig(c:/temp, Level.FINE);

        Platform.startup(config);
        // If using RE API in Eclipse/RCP application this is not needed.
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);
        IReportEngine engine = factory.createReportEngine(config);
        engine.changeLogLevel(Level.WARNING);
        IReportRunnable report = engine
                .openReportDesign("C:/Mine/BirtTraining/demo/demo.rptdesign");
        IRunAndRenderTask task = null;
        task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);
        HTMLRenderOption options = null;
        options = new HTMLRenderOption();
        options.setOutputFileName("C:/birt.html");
        task.setRenderOption(options);

        task.run();

         System.out.println("All went well. Closing program!");
         engine.destroy();
         System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("An error occured while running the report!");

        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Here is the exception:
Feb 1, 2015 6:32:13 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask createContentEmitter
SEVERE: Report engine can not create emitter null.
Feb 1, 2015 6:32:13 PM org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask handleFatalExceptions
SEVERE: An error happened while running the report. Cause:
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: **Report engine fails to initialize null emitter, please make sure required libraries for this emitter are installed.**
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.createContentEmitter(EngineTask.java:1770)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.doRun(RunAndRenderTask.java:106)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunAndRenderTask.run(RunAndRenderTask.java:77)
    at testBirt.Main.main(Main.java:46)

How can I initialize an emitter?
What are required libraries for the emitter?
If there is a complete example to generate a report it will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code with the Birt runtime 4_2_2 and it's working fine.Make sure you add all the dependencies present in the **birt-runtime-4_2_2\ReportEngine\lib** directory. Please cross check the import statement shown below :

[image]

I just added the report html output in the directory instead of **C:/birt.html**
`options.setOutputFileName("C:/export_dir/birt.html");`

You will find all the required jars in the Birt Report Engine's lib directory
**birt-runtime-4_2_2\ReportEngine\lib**

Below are the dependencies for your reference(Few of them you won't need to add in your project classpath):

```
org.eclipse.emf_2.6.0.v20130125-0826.jar                      
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.100.v20120522-1841.jar            
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.6.100.v20120522-1841.jar         
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.1.v20121031-182809.jar    
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.5.200.v20120522-1841.jar       
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.3.100.v20120522-1822.jar          
org.eclipse.osgi_3.8.2.v20130124-134944.jar                   
org.w3c.css.sac_1.3.0.v200805290154.jar                       
org.w3c.dom.smil_1.0.0.v200806040011.jar                      
org.w3c.dom.svg_1.1.0.v201011041433.jar                       
Tidy.jar                                                      
com.ibm.icu_4.4.2.v20110823.jar                               
js.jar                                                        
com.lowagie.text_2.1.7.v201004222200.jar                      
commons-cli-1.0.jar                                           
derby.jar                                                     
flute.jar                                                     
javax.wsdl_1.5.1.v201012040544.jar                            
javax.xml.stream_1.0.1.v201004272200.jar                      
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda_3.3.4.v201212070447.jar
org.apache.batik.parser_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar               
org.apache.batik.util_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar                 
org.apache.batik.xml_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar                  
org.apache.batik.bridge_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar               
org.apache.batik.css_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar                  
org.apache.batik.dom.svg_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar              
org.apache.batik.dom_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar                  
org.apache.batik.ext.awt_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar              
org.apache.batik.pdf_1.6.0.v201105071520.jar                  
org.apache.batik.svggen_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar               
org.apache.batik.transcoder_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar           
org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.6.0.v201011041432.jar
```

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep,
So, what are the needed dependencies here?

Comment: You are welcome. I modified the answer please check and add the required dependencies in your project classpath.

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, I will try and let u know the results.

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep, I have tried to import the jars, and it was run successfully too.
Some friends helped me to edit the above code to get it work using Birt 4.4.1 runtime libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code with Birt 4.4.1 runtime and it run successfully.

```
        try {
        System.setProperty("org.eclipse.datatools_workspacepath",
                "C:/Mine/abdo");
        intBirtEngine();
        // If using RE API in Eclipse/RCP application this is not needed.
        IReportEngineFactory factory = (IReportEngineFactory) Platform
                .createFactoryObject(IReportEngineFactory.EXTENSION_REPORT_ENGINE_FACTORY);

        IReportRunnable report = engine.openReportDesign(Main.class
                .getResourceAsStream("/pojo.rptdesign"));
        IRunAndRenderTask task = engine.createRunAndRenderTask(report);
        Map<String, List<StockData>> birtParams = new HashMap<String, List<StockData>>();
        birtParams.put("list",
                new StockDaoMock().getStockValues("Java"));
        System.out.println("my list\n"+new StockDaoMock().getStockValues("Java").size());
        task.setParameterValues(birtParams);

        IRenderOption options = new EXCELRenderOption();

        options.setOutputFormat("xls");
        options.setOutputFileName("C:/demo/birt9.xls");
        System.out.println(new Date());
        task.setRenderOption(options);

        task.run();
        task.close();

        destroyPlatform();

        System.out.println("All went well. Closing program!");
        System.exit(0);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("An error occured while running the report!");

        System.exit(-1);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Kuldeep for your efforts.